# How do I repeat template arguments a set number of times?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I'm writing a templated class, and I want to have a `tuple` that holds some data. The type of the `tuple` is related to the template arguments in this way:

```
template<typename ...Types>
class MyClass{
     public:
          std::tuple<int, (repeat "int" sizeof...(Types) times)> MyData;
}
```

For example, `MyClass<int, float, std::string, double>` would result in a `MyData` variable of type `std::tuple<int, int, int, int>`. I've looked into fold expressions, but I'm not sure that they can do what I want. Is there a way to do this in C++, and if so, how?

Comment: Why don't you use `std::array`? It's for most purposes equivalent to a tuple with a single repeated element type.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yep, that's a great idea. I'm just dumb

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the comments, use std::array. But, for completeness:

You can use `std::conditional`.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename ...Types>
struct TupleN { std::tuple<typename std::conditional<true, int, Types>::type...> MyData; };

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(TupleN<int, float, std::string, double>::MyData),
              std::tuple<int, int, int, int>>);
```

You could also roll your own:

```cpp
template<typename T> struct Ignore { using type = int; };
```